# how to move prometheus adapter to another namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, prometheus

For now I have prometheus and prometheus adapter in different namespaces:
[image: Text]

I tried to configure adapter YML but I was not successful:
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:

```
  annotations:
    deployment.kubernetes.io/revision: "2"
  creationTimestamp: "2020-01-30T08:49:05Z"
  generation: 2
  labels:
    app: prometheus-adapter
    chart: prometheus-adapter-2.0.1
    heritage: Tiller
    release: prometheus-adapter
  name: prometheus-adapter
  namespace: my-custom-namespace
  resourceVersion: "18513075"
  selfLink: /apis/apps/v1/namespaces/my-custom-namespace/deployments/prometheus-adapter
  ...
```

But I see error:

```
the namespace of the object (my-custom-namespace) does not match the namespace on the request (default)
```

How to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not edit an existing resource to change namespace.You need to delete the existing deployment first and then recreate the deployment in another namespace.

**Edit:**

With Helm2 you need to delete the release first `helm delete --purge release-name`  and then deploy it to different namespace as `helm install stable/prometheus-adapter --namespace namespace-name`

With helm 3 since there is no `--namespace` flag you need to delete the existing deployment and then redeploy it to a different namespace as below example to deploy metrics server.

```
$ helm install metricserver stable/metrics-server
Error: the namespace from the provided object "kube-system" does not          match the namespace "default". You must pass '--namespace=kube-system' to perform this operation.

$ helm install metricserver stable/metrics-server --namespace=kube-system
Error: the namespace from the provided object "kube-system" does not match the namespace "default". You must pass '--namespace=kube-system' to perform this operation.

$ kubectl config set-context kube-system --cluster=kubernetes --user=kubernetes-admin --namespace=kube-system
Context "kube-system" created.

$ kubectl config use-context kube-system
Switched to context "kube-system".

$ kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME                          CLUSTER      AUTHINFO           NAMESPACE
*         kube-system                   kubernetes   kubernetes-admin   kube-system
          kubernetes-admin@kubernetes   kubernetes   kubernetes-admin
          metallb                       kubernetes   kubernetes-admin   metallb
          nfstorage                     kubernetes   kubernetes-admin   nfstorage

$ helm install metricserver stable/metrics-server
NAME: metricserver
LAST DEPLOYED: 2019-05-26 14:37:45.582245559 -0700 PDT m=+2.942929639
NAMESPACE: kube-system
STATUS: deployed
```

Comment: I used helm to install adapter

Comment: after I removed prometheus adapter I can't install adapter with the same name: *cloudshell:~ (bx-dev-contactmatch)$ helm ls --all prometheus-adapter
NAME                    REVISION        UPDATED                         STATUS  CHART                           APP VERSION     NAMESPACE
prometheus-adapter      1               Thu Jan 30 11:49:04 2020        DELETED prometheus-adapter-2.0.1        v0.5.0          default*

Comment: use helm delete --purge release-name. This makes the name free for use in next install

Answer (score 1):

For helm 2 you can install the chart in any namespace you want by using:

`helm install stable/prometheus-adapter --name my-release --namespace foo`

Keep in mind that you need to remove the previous one.

This can be done using `helm delete --purge my-release`

Also there is a really nice article regarding changes in Helm3 [Breaking Changes in Helm 3 (and How to Fix Them)](https://itnext.io/breaking-changes-in-helm-3-and-how-to-fix-them-39fea23e06ff).